# Problem with GPIO PIN 4 (Physical pin 7)

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+

I have a simple LED circuit. I want to connect 3 LEDs to 3 different GPIO pins 2,3 & 4 (GPIO numbering).

Pins 2 and 3 works perfectly fine, but 4 wasn't working as expected.

I disconnected all the LEDs and wanted to check only 4 and wrote this code.

```
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) #GPIO PIN 4

GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)

sleep(120)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

After around 10s, LED turned off.

When I tried to keep LED ON using while loop, it started flashing after a while.

What is wrong with GPIO pin 4?

(Note: I am using Raspberry Pi 3b+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPIO4 is the default pin for the 1-Wire interface.

Make sure 1-Wire is disabled in Raspberry Pi Configuration, Interfaces.

Comment: Thanks Mike, 1-Wire was enabled on my Pi.